# error in 'chokidar.js' using 'dotenv-webpack'

Tags: reactjs, package

I've been using `dotenv-webpack` in my React project and I had an error. The error message is:

```
chokidar.js: 'return' outside of function. (4:1)

  2 | try {
  3 |   module.exports = require("chokidar");
> 4 |   return;
    |   ^
  5 | } catch(e) {
  6 |   v3Err = e;
  7 | }
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
```

And, this is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './i18n';

require('dotenv').config();

const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

When I remove the `Dotenv` configuration this error disappears, but I can't remove this package.

Does anyone know some solution?